# Why does `"a" < "b"` equal `true`?

Tags: ruby, string

Can someone explain how the following code works?

```
"a" < "b" #=> true 
"a" > "b" #=> false 
"a" < "B" #=> false 
"A" < "B" #=> true 
"A" < "b" #=> true 
"A" < "z" #=> true 
"z" < "A"
```

Comment: What result __did__ you expect?

Comment: I would like know how this code works, means why can't `"a" <  "B"`  true?

Comment: "don't know how the following code works" - it works by using [`Comparable#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html#method-i-3C), which is implemented in terms of operator `<=>` (the comparison operator in ruby). And strings know which one of them is "smaller" than the other.

Comment: Because A comes before B in the alphabet?

Comment: `strings know which one of them is "smaller" than the other` But how? Have those use ASCII code for comparison? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: "Have those use ASCII code for comparison" - pretty much that, yes. It's called "lexicographic order".

Comment: In fact, `String#<=>` does **not** explain how the comparison works, it just says _"Returns -1, 0, +1, or nil depending on whether string is less than, equal to, or greater than other_string"_

Comment: @Stefan: documentation doesn't. But the method implementation does. :)

Comment: Ruby is open source btw https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2050b50d85f89ce084c20089efe43785c35d8197/string.c#L3159. What is the problem to examine the source code if you have such a question for 2 years already?

Comment: @mudasobwa: C language is the problem. A big problem :) Although one must be able to read C in order to understand how things _really_ work. (cue Jörg coming in and mentioning rubinius, jruby and other non-C based rubies)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In two years [tag:c] could be rewritten from the scratch, not only learned :)

Comment: I tried looking at source code too. But i couldn't understand how that logic works. @mudasobwa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, both standard [Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L3159) and [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/string.rb#L2631) compare strings as they are saved in memory.

In C-Ruby with:

```
retval = memcmp(ptr1, ptr2, lesser(len1, len2))
```

and in Rubinius with:

```
@data.compare_bytes(other.__data__, @num_bytes, other.bytesize)
```

There are some additional checks (e.g. if `other` is also a String or if encodings are compatible), but when comparing `"a"` and `"b"`, Ruby basically compares `"a".bytes` and `"b".bytes`.

`String#bytes` returns an integer Array. In Ruby, Arrays aren't comparable by default, so you can launch

```
class Array
  include Comparable
end
```

before playing with `"a".bytes < "b".bytes` in the console.

Arrays, as strings, are compared according to the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

As an example:

```
class Array; include Comparable; end

p "a".bytes
# [97]
p "b".bytes
# [98]
p "a".bytes < "b".bytes
# true
p "a" < "b"
# true
p "B".bytes
# [66]
p "a".bytes < "B".bytes
# false
```

When comparing ASCII strings, it fits the description provided by [@AniketShivamTiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889028/6419007).

Finally, this behaviour isn't specific to Ruby. In a Linux folder, uppercase filenames are sorted before the lowercase ones (at least when `LC_COLLATE="C"`).

Comment: very nicely explained

Answer (score 4):

When checking for the condition it is converting into ASCII codes and then comparing the result. Here is the [link](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
    "a" < "b"  
     => true 
    When it converts so a = 97 & b = 98 In ASCII 
    And 97 < 98 which is true 

    "a" > "b"
     => false 
    When it converts so a = 97 & b = 98 In ASCII 
    And 97 > 98 which is false

    "a" < "B"
     => false 
    When it converts so a = 97 & B = 66 In ASCII 
    And 97 < 66 which is false 

    "A" < "B"
     => true 
    When it converts so A = 65 & B = 66 In ASCII 
    And 65 < 66 which is true

    "A" < "b"
     => true 
   When it converts so A = 65 & b = 98 In ASCII 
    And 65 < 98 which is true
```

I hope you got my point

Comment: Please fix your formatting, so that non-code is not in the code block. :)

Comment: This is plain wrong. `ruby -e 'puts "я" <=> "ф"'` results in [proper] `1`, while neither `я`, nor `ф` do not have ASCII codes at all.

Comment: @mudasobwa- you can see here http://www.addressmunger.com/hex_ascii_tables/ . "я" has a greater value than "ф" that is why it is  giving 1

Comment: Then can you please explain how this works @mudasobwa

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: ASCII codes are 0-127 (7 bit). Anything beyond that is not ASCII and is up to interpretation on the target machine. Ever wondered why even "latin" family [has several encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table)? That's why, because different people had different opinion as to what symbol these bytes should map to.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It's not plain wrong. It's only half of the story. If both strings only use 7-bit ascii, the answer is correct. See [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L3134). Since the question only uses latin letters, this answer is relevant, though badly formatted.

Comment: @EricDuminil this answer states “it is converting into ASCII codes and then comparing the result.” Nothing is converted and surely not ASCII codes are compared (see the link to [tag:c] code of `string.c` I linked in comments.) The fact that this assumption leads to the same result on a tiny subset (≈60 characters) does not mean this answer is somehow relevant to what actually happening there.

Comment: @mudasobwa: AFAICT, `rb_str_cmp` mostly delegates to `memcmp`, which compares bytes in lexicographic order. True, it doesn't convert anything. Still, ASCII strings are compared as ASCII codes.

Comment: @EricDuminil right, it’s compared byte by byte. Strictly speaking, it’s not a lexicographical order: `ruby -e 'puts ["á" <=> "aa", "á" <=> "aя"].inspect'` [surprisingly] results in `[1, -1]`, exactly because of generic `memcmp`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: What's surprising in your example? It seems consistent to the result you'd get by adding `.bytes` to every string.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, it follows `bytes` but it does not follow a human common sense: one letter compared to two letters should not depend on the second letter, should it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a comparison of the byte value of the character. You can view the raw byte-value of your char with `bytes` method:

```
'B'.bytes
=> [66]

'a'.bytes
=> [97]
```

So now you can see why `'B'` is less than `'a'`

Comment: Did you take a look at the other answers before writing yours?

Comment: @EricDuminil apologies, none other answers spelled it out plainly that it was a `byte` value comparison, and gave a concise example. Mentioning ASCII value might muddy the waters, especially when dealing with a comparison that has unicode characters.

Comment: Please read my answer again. I specifically mention `bytes`. I don't see any new information in your answer